# Highcharts - How to I disable a series when I enable another one?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart where I have about 5 series. But it makes no sense having two of them enabled at the same time. When my page loads one is enabled and one is disabled based on backend code - which is fine. But obviously the user can enable the second series by clicking on the legend. Can someone share some quick JS code that disables series B when series A is enabled? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `legendItemClick` event callback function and toggle visibility of the opposite series.

```
    series: [..., {
        ...,
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function() {
                this.chart.series[4].setVisible();
            }
        }
    }, {
        ...,
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function() {
                this.chart.series[3].setVisible();
            }
        },
        visible: false
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tpj26vqw/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.events.legendItemClick

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for